# Gson serialization error with val in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, serialization, gson, retrofit2

I am using Gson v2.8.2 and Retrofit v2.3.0 and I have two classes, Answer.kt:

```
open class Answer(@SerializedName("answer")
                  var text: String,
                  val id: Int)
```

and AnswerSummary.kt:

```
class AnswerSummary(val answer: Answer) : Answer(answer.text, answer.id) {
    val percent: Int = 0
}
```

I am using it in a list (in Java, still migrating to Kotlin):

```
public List<AnswerSummary> getAnswerSummaries() {
            return answerSummaries;
        }
```

I get an error when `val` is not removed: `class AnswerSummary(val answer: Answer) ...`:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create converter for class com.name.app.model.response.AnswerResponse
....
Caused by java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class com.name.app.model.pojo.AnswerSummary declares multiple JSON fields named answer
       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:170)
       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:100)
       at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:423)
       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.create(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:53)
       ....
```

After removing 'val': `class AnswerSummary(answer: Answer) ...`, the error goes away. Why is this, since I only annotated one field? - `@SerializedName("answer") var text: String`.

I found a way to circumvent the crash while still maintaining immutability ('val') - By using a different variable name: `class AnswerSummary(val ans: Answer) ...`. What is happening behind the background - is it related to the fact that the @SerializedName field value is the same as the variable name?

Comment: `AnswerSummary declares multiple JSON fields named answer` Rename `val answer` in `AnswerSummary(val answer: Answer)` to something else.

Comment: i mentioned that i circumvent the crash when i use a different variable name: `class AnswerSummary(val ans: Answer)`, I'm asking what's going on: _why_ do I have to remove 'val' _or_ change the variable name?

Comment: Because Retrofit is _Unable to create converter for class com.name.app.model.response.AnswerResponse_ because of _AnswerSummary declares multiple JSON fields named answer_. What would you do on the Retrofit's place? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to rename the `answer` parameter:

```
class AnswerSummary(val ans: Answer) : Answer(ans.text, ans.id) { ... }
```

or use `answer` as parameter, not property:

```
class AnswerSummary(answer: Answer) : Answer(answer.text, answer.id) { ... }
```

It will work because when you are using `val` parameter 'answer' is considered as a property (without `val` it is considered as parameter) and serialized by Gson using property name as serialized name. At the same time you have the same serialized name `@SerializedName("answer")` in your base class `Answer` , therefore there is a conflict while properties are being serialized.

Comment: why must I rename the variable? is it because @SerializedName is also "answer"?

Comment: yes, the error "class com.name.app.model.pojo.AnswerSummary declares multiple JSON fields named answer" says that there are multiple fields named `answer`

Comment: using the @Expose annotation still results in the app crashing. what if the serialized field value was changed (in the backend api) to _"ANSWER"_ instead of _"answer"_, do you know if that would avoid the crash? i know i can rename the parameter but answer is much cleaner to read than `ans` or `answerParam`. my backup option is to remove 'val' because crashes only occur when i add 'val'.

Comment: I think renaming serialized value in the backend api to "ANSWER" could help, but I'm not sure, you can try.

Comment: yes, i believe you're right. how come whenever i remove 'val' from the method signature the error disappears. why does 'val' make the issue come up?

Comment: I think it's because when you are using `val` it is considered as a property (without `val` it is considered as parameter) and serialized by Gson using property name as serialized name. At the same time you have the same serialized name `@SerializedName("answer")` in your base class `Answer `, therefore there is a conflict while properties are being serialized.

Comment: @chornge, I edited my answer regarding using `Expose` annotation. Please check if it works for you.

Comment: still crashes with `@Expose`, you can edit your answer to include your explanation for using 'val'.